# New modem, connects to network w/o internet

Tags: windows-10, networking

so I installed my new modem, it works writing this on my laptop using a wired connection, but for the life of me I cannot get my desktop to connect to the internet. So onto the things I have tried:

1. ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew

   this varies between telling me it cannot connect to dhcp or that there is no valid IP address
2. ipconfig /flushdns and ipconfig /registerdns

   no errors but it doesn't seem to help
3. disable the device in device manager then enable.

   no dice
4. uninstall from device manager and rescan

   no dice
5. try restarting the dhcp client service

   ```
   5a. cant do it other process depend on this

   5b. stopping dependent services first...not allowed

   5c.  edit permissions in regedit then stop them .... 1061 service cant accept commands

   5d. find the service pid and kill it in powershell ... nope just restarts itself
   ```
6. try some more commands netsh winsock reset and netsh int ip reset

So I have turned my computer off and on about 100 times and am out of ideas and I cant find any post that covers all of these steps not working...help, please!

Comment: Use the same IP+x gateway and filter as ethernet without auto iP

Comment: I did try transferring my laptops ipconfig to my desktop and changing the IP. but it just says it cant contact my dhcp server. I feel like the new modem is enforcing ipv6 and i have absolutely no idea how to manually configure a ipv6 adapter

Comment: When manual IP, DHCP is off.  iPV6 may be deleted

Comment: I know. but if dhcp is not working what are my options?

Comment: As i said choose IP , filter like 255.255.255.0 and same gateway

Comment: yep. sorry but, that did not change anything.

Comment: What model modem/router?

Comment: netgear cm1200.

Comment: Are you trying to connect both at the same time? You need a router as well to do that.

Comment: (1) Why did you install this *"new"* modem?  (2) How is the *"desktop"* connected to this *"network"*?  (3) What are the connections of this network?  (4) Is there a router/gateway for this "network"?

Comment: Does anything work?

Comment: hey so I apreciate the attempts to help, figured I would leave a resolution here for posterity. I was an idiot thought the modem was also a router because it had 4 ports...so I plugged in my old router into the equation...i dont know why but it was completely screwed could only use the connection on one pc and not any others connected to the router..so i rush shipped a tplink wired router plugged it in and everything worked. my old router is now just my access point..

Comment: have you tried checking under Network Connections to see if the active Ethernet interface has a static IP and Gateway assigned? Most likely this is the problem. I suspect at some point you assigned a static IP and the new modem uses a different netrange or gateway assignment.

Comment: so what happened here is that when setting up the new modem my isp assigned the WAN directly to my work laptop. My router at the time did not have an interface to change that. as soon as I plugged in my new router I reassigned the wan port from my laptop to the modem and everythin was fixed.